# Get all site collections for a web application - JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom, content-editor-web-part

I want to display all site collections for a given web application(Can be hard-coded url) using JSOM SharePoint 2010(No REST api). I have tried but couldn't complete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JS CSOM only operates on the site you are currently on (You can open another client context but you need a site URL to do so). It does not allow you to do any operations based on the webapp level. If you want to execute those statements you need to user other ways.

A nice and simple approach would be to query the search via REST. You can apply a filter to only retrieve Sitecollections and you can also filter by path.

A filter for Sitecollections can be don't via the **contentclass** managed property with a value of **sts_site**.

Have a look here for some values you can use:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/02/16/sharepoint-power-searching-using-contentclass/

Comment: Is that means we can't do it in JS?

Comment: No.... You just need to loosen your constrains (No REST calls)

Comment: Sorry 2010 I noticed... You need to use the search soap webservice to access results https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcsearch.queryservice(v=office.14).aspx